# Stative passive with ‘vertreten’

Tags: modal-verb, passive

I read this sentence:

> Auf der Hochzeit war jedes Alter vertreten.

This seemed odd to me, because I would have said **wurde vertreten** instead.   A German-speaking friend said that **wurde** would sound strange here, but she could not explain the grammatical rule behind it.  Can someone explain the use of the stative passive here?

Comment: The expression here is _vertreten sein_ = being present, being  represented.

Comment: "wurde jedes Alter vertreten" in your sentence would actually end up in meaning like: "A youngster represented the pensionists and a middle-aged the youngster"... and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the comment above, the word is *vertreten sein* which means to be physically present.

*vertreten werden*, on the other hand, means to be represented by someone else (e.g. when you couldn't attend yourself due to health issues and send someone else instead).

Answer (score 0):

The stative passive (with *sein*) describes a *status* while the dynamic passive (with *werden*) describes an *action.*

In your example, every age *is being represented* at the wedding. There is no action involved, the ages are just being there. If you used *werden* then something is actively being represented: I could be going to a counter to actively represent something there.

Comment: Stative passive,is it not'Zustandpassiv' e.g. der Laden ist geschlossen?

Comment: @user1474062 Sorry, what’s your question?